# How to implement zip (or combine) function for iterating over two containers in C++?

Tags: c++, for-loop, tuples

I'd like to implement iteration over two vectors in a way like this:

```
for (auto& [i, j]: zip(v1, v2))
    j = i;
```

The `zip` function, `begin`, `end` and `operator ++` could be implemented easily:

```
template <class T1, class T2> inline tuple<T1&, T2&> zip (T1& t1, T2& t2) {return {t1, t2}; }

template <class T1, class T2> auto begin (tuple<T1, T2>& t)
{
    tuple r = {get<0>(t).begin(), get<1>(t).begin()};
    return r;
}

template <class T1, class T2> auto end (tuple<T1, T2>& t)
{
    tuple r = {get<0>(t).end(), get<1>(t).end()};
    return r;
}

template <class T1, class T2> tuple<T1, T2>& operator ++ (tuple<T1, T2>& t)
{
    ++get<0>(t);
    ++get<1>(t);
    return t;
}
```

but the problem is in the `operator *` because it should return a reference. Naive implementation fails:

```
template <class T1, class T2> auto& operator * (tuple<T1, T2>& t)
{
    tuple r = {*get<0>(t), *get<1>(t) }
    return r;  // return reference to local
}
```

Boost implements something like this somehow, but I'd prefer not to rely on boost in my project. Could I implement `operator *` in this way or should I follow completely different way?

UPD. Thanks to @SamVarshavchik and @IgorTandetni comments I've fixed zip and implemented combined iterator

```
template <class T1, class T2> inline tuple<T1&, T2&> zip (T1& t1, T2& t2) {return {t1, t2}; }

template <class T1, class T2> class iterator2
{
public:
    iterator2 (T1 _i1, T2 _i2): i1(_i1), i2(_i2), i({i1,i2}) {}
    tuple<T1&, T2&>& operator * () {return i; }
    const tuple<T1&, T2&>& operator * () const {return i; }
    iterator2& operator ++ () {++i1; ++i2; return *this; }
    bool operator != (const iterator2& t) {return i1 != t.i1; }
private:
    T1 i1;
    T2 i2;
    tuple<T1&, T2&> i;
};

template <class T1, class T2> auto begin (tuple<T1, T2>& t)
{
    return iterator2(get<0>(t).begin(), get<1>(t).begin());
}

template <class T1, class T2> auto end (tuple<T1, T2>& t)
{
    return iterator2(get<0>(t).end(), get<1>(t).end());
}
```

Unfortunately this way I have to use `*i` and `*j` instead of `i` and `j` in the loop:

```
for (auto& [i, j]: zip(v1, v2))
    *j = *i;
```

The problem is that `operator *` returns `tuple<T1&, T2&>&` while it should be a tuple of the result of `T1` and `T2` dereference. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Instead of your iterator being implemented as a `std::tuple`, implement your iterator as a real class, with a proper `operator*`, instead of attempting to implement a global `operator*` overload for a tuple.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, if I implement it as a class of two fields for two iterators `T1 i1; T2 i2;`, would it make any difference? Returning `{*i1, *i2}` would be returning a reference-to-local again. Should I create a tupple of two references like `tupple <T1&, T2&> r`, initialize it as `{i1, i2}` in the constructor and return it in `operator *`? I've tried it, but it doesn't worked. First of all `i` and `j` became iterators in the for-loop, not references, and `*i` and `*j` was reading vectors well, but not writing, i.e. the `v2` stay unchanged after the loop.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, looks like I need field like `tupple <`type of dereference of T1`&, `'type of dereference of T2'`&>` to initialize it as `{*i1, *i2}`, but not sure if it is possible.

Comment: Range iteration uses a discrete iterator. As such, returning a reference to a local variable is well-formed, since the iterator remains in scope, and it exists for the duration of range iteration.

Comment: As an initial matter, `zip(v1, v2)` already returns copies of `v1` and `v2`, in a tuple. No matter what happens next, the original `v1` and `v2` can't possibly be modified. `zip` probably needs to return a class holding references to `v1` and `v2`. That class would implement `begin` and `end` to return something similar to `boost::zip_iterator` - a class holding iterators into `v1` and `v2`. For that class, `operator*` would return, by value, a tuple of references to corresponding elements of `v1` and `v2`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thank you, I've missed it. @IgorTandetnik @SamVarshavchik Unfortunately I still can't catch how to implement `operator *` in better way. I've updated question to address this problem.

Comment: You are trying to return a tuple of iterators from `operator*`. You should return a tuple of references to elements those iterators point to. As in `tuple<decltype(*it1)&, decltype(*it2)&>`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik but I can't store such tupple as a field since it would be constructor-initialized reference to a single container's element and reference would not be changed in case of iterator changing. And I can't create such tupple in the operator since it would be returning reference to local again. And I can't just return a copy because for loop would not understand it.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to store it as a field? Why do you believe you can't return a copy? What happens when you try?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `auto operator * () {return tuple<decltype(*i1)&, decltype(*i2)&>{*i1, *i2}; }`, fails at `for (auto& [i, j]: zip(v1, v2))`: `cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type «std::tuple<int&, int&>&» to an rvalue of type «std::tuple<int&, int&>»`. I can change to `for (auto [i, j]: zip(v1, v2))` or to `for (auto&& [i, j]: zip(v1, v2))`. Both works but not sure which one is correct and better. 

I supposed that I should always use `for (auto& i: container)` when I need to change container content via `i` variable, not `for (auto i: container)`.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use `auto [i, j]` or `auto&& [i, j]` - both would work equally well. Yes, you would normally use `for (auto& i: container)` when you want to modify a container - but `zip(v1, v2)` doesn't return a container (and I believe `iterator2` is not an iterator in the standard library sense - it doesn't fulfill all iterator requirements, one of which is that `operator*` actually return a reference to the iterator's `value_type`. It just pretends to be an iterator well enough to fool the range-for loop).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, thank you. That's probably an acceptable solution.